# local equation in the definition of transversal intersection

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth surface and $C,D$ be two smooth curves on it. In Hartshorne page-$357$, it is stated that if $p \in C \cap D$ is a point of intersection of $C$ and $D$ , we say that $C$ and $D$ meet transversally at $p$ if the local equations $f,g$ of $C,D$ at $P$ generate the maximal ideal $m_p$ of $\mathcal O_X, p$.

My question is that, what is the precise algebraic definition of the *local equation* of a curve at a point in this context?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

An effective Cartier divisor is a closed immersion $i : D \rightarrow X$ that is locally cut out by a single equation, and it's not a zero divisor. That is: for every point $p$ there is an affine open set $U =Spec(R)$ such that the closed immersion $i$ on $U$ corresponds to $Spec(R / (a)) \rightarrow Spec(R)$ for some $a \in R$, and $a$ is not a zero divisor.

That $a$ is the local equation of the divisor.

Comment: Does it necessarily follow from here that $a \in \mathcal O_{X,p}$?

Comment: $a \in R$, so if $p \in U$ then the restriction of $a$ is an element in $O_{X, p}$.

Comment: why it is the equation? There could be another affine open $V$ containing $p$, so we get another element $b$ there (right)?

Comment: Yes, but remember that closed immersions correspond to quasicoherent sheaves of ideals. So even if $a$ and $b$ are not the same element, when restricted to an affine open set containing both $a$ and $b$, they generate the same ideal. Therefore they differ by multiplying by a unit. Therefore transversal intersection is independent of the choice of affine open.